# How to render both PDF and Excel using the same erb rails template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet, erb, wicked-pdf

I have a Rails ERB template that starts like this:

```
  <table style="width: 32%; display: inline-table; float:left; background-color:#EAEAEA; margin-right: 10px">
    <thead >
     <tr style="background-color:#BFBFBF; border: 1pt solid #A6A6A6">
       <th>CASH BALANCE</th>
       <td>
       <td><%=@report_previous_day%></td>
       <td><%=@report_day%></td>

     </tr>
     <tr style="background-color:#D9D9D9; border-left: 1pt solid #A6A6A6; border-right: 1pt solid #A6A6A6">
      <th style = "padding-right: 5px">Entity</th>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <td style = "padding-right: 5px"><%=@report_previous_date_string%></td>
      <td style = "padding-right: 5px"><%=@report_date_string%></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I am using wicked_pdf gem to render teh above template as a PDF. That works like a charm.

Is there a way to render the same erb template shown above as a spreadsheet as well? I need to be able to do this; please help!

Comment: The closest gem to my requirement seems to be one named "to_spreadsheet" -  https://github.com/glebm/to_spreadsheet

But it uses .haml files; any idea if it could use html.erb file?

Comment: From the top of README: to_spreadsheet lets your Rails 3+ app render Excel files using the existing slim/haml/erb/etc views.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk - Thank you for your response. Just a quick question? Would I be able to use the contents of a .html.erb file inside a .haml.erb file? (I only ask because I need to use a pretty huge template file - I already have that file in .html.erb file format; since haml is an abstraction over html, it would save me a lot of effort if I could reuse the contents from the .html.erb file in the .haml.erb file as well. Or even better, if I could use the .html.erb file directly in this gem, that'd be the best option for me!

Comment: You can use [partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials). They can be either .haml or .erb.

Comment: I.e. you can call .haml "sub-template" from .erb "top-level template" and vice versa.

Comment: @pavelmikhailyuk - thanks much for the inputs. I was able to use just .html.erb templates and it worked!! However the color schemes that came up in the PDF don't appear in the Excel. Would you be able to help with this please? I have posted another question for this issue.